# Quitar "un software automatizado de pruebas esta controlando" en Cypress

Tags: cypress

llevo varias días intentando programar un script en cypress para automatizar la descarga de informes, el problema es que para acceder a la plataforma en la que se encuentras dichos informes hay que iniciar sesión a traves de microsft(hay verificación en dos pasos también). Antes usaba selenium en python y conseguí que el navegador no se ejecutase en modo software de automatizacion mediante este código de aqui:

```
# Configurar opciones de Chrome
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False) 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium-cookies")
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

Este codigo en en python con selenium se encargaba de eliminar este mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que necesito hacer lo mismo pero esta vez en cypress, hacer que el navegador no se ejecute con software de automatización para que no tenga que iniciar sesión cada vez que se ejecuta el script (si se puede hacer con google chrome sería aún mejor, en su defecto con otro navegador también es una opción).
Este es el único código que tengo en el fichero cypress.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import preprocessor from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import browserify from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/browserify'



async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

 

  on("file:preprocessor", browserify.default(config));

 

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}

 

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    defaultCommandTimeout: 0,
    baseUrl: "https://enel.service-now.com/navpage.do",
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/integration/**/*.feature",
    supportFile: false,
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```